# Отправление сообщения об ошибке клиенту

Tags: java, udp

Доброго времени суток. Имеется UDP сервер, который вычисляет значение полученного мат. выражения.

Если сервер получает нечто в неправильном формате, то срабатывает исключение, где выводится соответствующее сообщение об ошибке.

Как отправить сообщение об ошибке еще и клиенту?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class UDPServer {
    public static final int LENGTH_PACKET = 30;
    public static final String HOST = "localhost";
    public static final int PORT = 2345;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
        ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        DatagramSocket servSocket = null;
        DatagramPacket datagram;
        byte[] data;
        try {
            servSocket = new DatagramSocket(PORT);
            while (true) {
                data = new byte[LENGTH_PACKET];
                datagram = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
                servSocket.receive(datagram);
                String s = (new String(datagram.getData())).trim();
                System.out.println("Полученое выражение: " + s);
                String result = engine.eval(s).toString();
                System.out.println("Результат вычислений: " + result);
                datagram.setData(result.getBytes());
                datagram = new DatagramPacket(datagram.getData(), datagram.getData().length, datagram.getAddress(), datagram.getPort());
                servSocket.send(datagram);
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            System.err.println("Не удаётся открыть сокет : " + e.toString());
        } catch (ScriptException ex) {
            System.err.println("Некорректное выражение");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Ошибка");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас есть байтовый массив, который вы пересылаете, определите некий свой стандарт, где например первые N байт будут с данными, а последующие M байт - сообщение об ошибке. Либо сделайте какие-то идентификаторы, например специальные байтовые последовательности, которые однозначно будут идентифицировать то, что лежит в следующих элементах массива. Обычно это так делается. Можно костыльно, в случае ошибки просто заполнять данные сообщением об ошибке, а на клиенте аналогично - парсить число, а если не распарсилось, считать что ошибка и пытаться считать сообщение об ошибке. Но это не очень хорошо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого вам придется немного разнести ваши try-catch, чтобы ошибки вычисления обрабатывались отдельно от ошибок сети.

Лучше всего это вынести в отдельную функцию (не лучшая функция с точки зрения Single Responsibility, чисто для демонстрации идеи):

```
String calculateAndFormatAnswer() {
    try {
        return "ResOk: " + engine.eval(s).toString();
    } catch (ScriptException ex) {
        return "ResFail: " ex.getMessage(); // или так: return "ResFail: Некорректное выражение";
    }
}
```

Тогда на клиенте вы уже будете обрабатывать так:

```
if (answer.startsWith("ResOk") {...}
```

Если же вы захотите получать на клиенте не просто сообщение, а целый объект исключения, вам придется почитать о сериализации, но это уже отдельный вопрос, потому что способов довольно много.